# Transactions not working in Django using MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, django, transactions, data-integrity

I am regularily getting integrity errors for the following code snippet:

```
 class StatsManager(Manager):

    @transaction.atomic
     def create(self, **kwargs):
         kwargs.setdefault('date', date.today())
         try:
             obj = self.get_queryset().get(**kwargs)
         except self.model.DoesNotExist:
             obj = super().create(hits=1, **kwargs)  # line 28
         else:
             obj.hits = F('hits') + 1
             obj.save()
         return obj
```

Here is the error message:

```
IntegrityError at /emploi/cours-particuliers-en-physique-chimie-en-classe-de-superieur-1-evry-14skb.html
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'EMP_VIEW-1903259-2018-01-08' for key 'statEvent'")
```

And the traceback:

```
File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/stats/models/managers.py" in create                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  26.             obj = self.get_queryset().get(**kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  380.                 self.model._meta.object_name

      During handling of the above exception (Stats matching query does not exist.), another exception occurred:


File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_mysql/monkey_patches.py" in execute

  35.         return orig_execute(self, sql, args)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  411.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  374.         db.query(q)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  277.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)


      The above exception ((1062, "Duplicate entry 'EMP_VIEW-1903259-2018-01-08' for key 'statEvent'")) was the direct cause of the following exception:



File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/channels/handler.py" in process_exception_by_middleware 
  243.             return super(AsgiHandler, self).process_exception_by_middleware(exception, request)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/utils/views/behaviors.py" in dispatch
  343.             return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/offers/views/public.py" in dispatch
  1089.         return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/offers/views/public.py" in get
  1308.         return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/stats/views/behaviors.py" in get
  16.                                  target_id=self.object.pk)

File "/usr/lib/python3.4/contextlib.py" in inner
  30.                 return func(*args, **kwds)

File "/home/www/aladom_v6/www/stats/models/managers.py" in create
  28.             obj = super().create(hits=1, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in create
  394.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  808.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  838.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  924.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  963.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1107.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py" in reraise
  685.             raise value.with_traceback(tb)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django_mysql/monkey_patches.py" in execute
  35.         return orig_execute(self, sql, args)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  250.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  50.         raise errorvalue

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  247.             res = self._query(query)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _query
  411.         rowcount = self._do_query(q)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in _do_query
  374.         db.query(q)

File "/home/www/.virtualenvs/aladom/lib/python3.4/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in query
  277.             _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
```

Line 28 raises a duplicate entry error while I checked right above whether the key exists or not, and encapsulated it in a transaction.

I'm using Django 1.11, so I tried to set MySQL isolation level to `read committed`. I thought it would fix that issue, but it still occurs.

I also tried to do it the other way round:

```
 class StatsManager(Manager):

     def create(self, **kwargs):
         kwargs.setdefault('date', date.today())
         try:
             obj = super().create(hits=1, **kwargs)
         except IntegrityError:
             obj = self.get_queryset().get(**kwargs)  # line 27
             obj.hits = F('hits') + 1
             obj.save()
         return obj
```

But in this case, it sometimes fail with the following error, because my requests are encapsulated in transactions:

```
TransactionManagementError at /admin/moderation/serviceoffermoderation/248424/change/
An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

Which is actually expected, unlike the former error.

Any idea what's going on and how to deal with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could rewrite your code to use `get_or_create`, which has some handling for race conditions.

To avoid the *An error occurred in the current transaction* error, you need to wrap the code that can raise the `IntegrityError` with transaction.atomic:

```
 def create(self, **kwargs):
     kwargs.setdefault('date', date.today())
     try:
         with transaction.atomic():
             obj = super().create(hits=1, **kwargs)
     except IntegrityError:
         obj = self.get_queryset().get(**kwargs)  # line 27
         obj.hits = F('hits') + 1
         obj.save()
     return obj
```

See the docs on [controlling transactions explicitly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) for more info.